Font awesome kit index.d.ts is empty
I've just purchased FA Pro and created a kit. The kit has been installed via npm and is successfully located within the node_modules, with all the corresponding svgs.
However, the index.d.ts file is an empty export
export {};

On the other hand, the free version has this
export const fa0: IconDefinition;
export const fa1: IconDefinition;
export const fa2: IconDefinition;
export const fa3: IconDefinition;
...
it goes on

This means that I can't (or don't know how) import my icons to the angular component.
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { all } from '@awesome.me/kit-XXXXXXX/icons'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-diagnostic-trials',
  templateUrl: './diagnostic-trials.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./diagnostic-trials.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ActionBarComponent, NewTrialComponent, ResultsAndReportsComponent, FontAwesomeModule]
})
export class DiagnosticTrialsComponent implements OnInit {
  faCoffee = faCoffee;

  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService, private ehseMessageService: EhseMessageService) {
    library.add(...all);
   }
}

<div>
  <fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon> <!-- this one does work -->
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i> <!-- this one doesn't, how can I import it from the kit? -->
</div>

